# How works association's model?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm beginner in Sails Js and I can't understand how association's model works. I grow up with relacional method and I can't abstract my thought to understand how I can do this. I only see relations via ID for join tables.

I read Waterline and Sails Js documentation and did exemples... But I can't see how things happen. Furthermore, I wanna save in mongo schema.
Like:

```
// User Model
user_list {
uid,
social:{
    facebook:{
        uid,
        accessToken
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for all, guys.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sur I fully understand your problem but maybe this will give you more clue on how associations work in sails.

As far as I know you cannot nest your object attributes in sails. What you must do, as you would have done in a relational database is create two models.

I understand that you want to build a One-to-One association between your User model and your Social model.

You can do something like this:

#### User model attributes

```
uid : {
 type : 'integer',
 unique : 'true'
 },

social : {
  model : 'social'
}
```

#### Social model attributes

```
type :{
  type : 'string',
  in : ['facebook', 'twitter', 'other']
}

uid :{
  model : 'user',
}

accessToken : {
   type : 'string',
   required : 'true'
}
```

Note that by default sails use the documentId as reference and not the uid defined here.

Hope this will help a bit.

Comment: Thanks @adc06!
I understand what you said perfectly. It seems like magic!
I found a [doc of waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md) that opened my eyes.